# How to read just one table from a csv using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm new to pandas and I need to read csv files for some statistical analysis. However the csv files I currently have are not very organised and clean. [Example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17l5M6rK5qG-3XnP5O_RQ61geif_ThvtR/view?usp=sharing) of the files I have. My goal is to read only the Field, X, Y fields under 1 of the TRAJECTORIES table (and ignore the ANALOG and FORCE PLATES tables). So that I end with this:

```
Field      X           Y
1      -9.229193   -533.886230
2      -9.091076   -533.673645
3      -9.229520   -533.899353
```

and so on.

This data was generated by a tracker software suite and there was no way to generate them without the other two tables. Secondly, I have almost 1200 such files so its manually a hectic task to go through them all and remove the other tables.

Thanks for any help and suggestions.

Comment: Could not make out anything from the google drive doc u shared. So, off the top of my head i assume there is some delineation between the tables. If that is so, you could write a script in python using d csv reader and break off when u get to the rows u r not interested in for each file. The other option is if u r working on a Linux machine u could do some piping with cut and grep to get ur required fields and filter just for the rows u want. Again just previous experience at play here. Since I can’t see ur docs

Comment: If the rows in the TRAJECTORIES table you want to read in are always between rows 11 and 107 in your csv then you can use some of the parameters in the `read_csv` function to only read in these lines e.g. `read_csv(filepath = "myfile.csv", header=11, skiprows=10, nrows=96)

Comment: @meenaparam Good suggestion. But it doesn't work because unfortunately the number of rows varies across all my files.